# Capitalization Police: Why all the capitals?

Tags: capitalization, questions, dialogue

I'm writing an essay where I want to talk about introspection. I've written the following sentence and Microsoft Word is insisting on capitalizing every single 'w' even though this is essentially a single sentence.

> I ask myself, *what* went well? *what* went wrong? *what* could I have done to make things better?

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer atm, but briefly: this is archaic if not obsolete usage, and Word does not handle archaisms at all well.

Comment: I ask myself, *what went well, what went wrong, what could I have done to make things better?*

Comment: I ask myself, what went well; what went wrong; what I could have done to make things better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion over capitalisation may stem from the fact that your sentence does not sound to me like a question. It sounds more like a moment of self reflection.

*I ask myself what went well, what went wrong and what could I have done to make things better.*

Software obviously will not detect this, especially if you insert question marks.

Answer (score 8):

Your capitalization of what you call a sentence violates the convention whereby a question mark indicates the end of a sentence. According to that same convention, your query text is actually three separate sentences.

That's why MS Word's grammar checker is nagging you.

Comment: And the fact that it's stupid enough to be taken in this way is a good reason to turn it off. Spellcheck and grammar check on wordprocessors are a waste of time and do no useful work.